# Getting a certain class from an element using wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to get the class starting with logo, only example item is:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // add classes to tab items
  var listItems = $(".vc_tta-tab a");
  // loop through all tab items
  listItems.each(function(idx, item) {
    var listItem = $(item);
    var tabID = listItem.attr("href");
    console.log(tabID);
    var matchCard = $(tabID).find('[class^="logo-"]');
    var tabClass = $(tabID).attr("class");
    console.log(tabClass);
    console.log(matchCard);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_general vc_tta vc_tta-tabs vc_tta-color-grey vc_tta-style-classic vc_tta-shape-rounded vc_tta-spacing-1 vc_tta-tabs-position-top vc_tta-controls-align-left">
  <div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
    <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
      <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-symantec" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Symantec SSL/TLS Certificates</span></a></li>
      <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-geotrust" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">GeoTrust SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
      <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-rapidssl" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">RapidSSL Certificates</span></a></li>
      <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-thawte" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Thawte SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
      <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-certum" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Certum SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
      <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-comodo" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Comodo SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panels-container">
    <div class="vc_tta-panels">
      <div class="vc_tta-panel vc_active logo-ssl-symantec" id="ssl-brand-symantec" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
          <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-symantec" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Symantec SSL/TLS Certificates</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-geotrust" id="ssl-brand-geotrust" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
          <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-geotrust" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">GeoTrust SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-rapidssl" id="ssl-brand-rapidssl" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
          <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-rapidssl" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">RapidSSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-thawte" id="ssl-brand-thawte" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
          <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-thawte" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Thawte SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-certum" id="ssl-brand-certum" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
          <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-certum" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Certum SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-comodo" id="ssl-brand-comodo" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
          <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-comodo" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Comodo SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is working by finding ID and matching that but can't get it to select that class I am wanting.

Also, I then want to take that class and set to the parent element of the initial href.

Comment: you don't have any .vc_tta-tab elements in your HTML in that snippet, right?

Comment: I do, let me update the markup now

Comment: what you want is to get the class name of the elements starting with logo- or the element itself?

Comment: Are you saying you want to (a) find elements with a class that starts with `"logo-"`, and then (b) get that class name as a string so that you can add the class to some other element? *" i then want to take that class and set to the parent element of the initial href"* - What is the "initial href"? The elements in your HTML that have a `logo-` class are all divs, they don't have an `href`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting what I believe you are wanting (which is to select a class that starts with `logo-`, then you could use [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), also known as a Regex.

I would use `/^logo-[^ ]*/g` as the Regex.

The `/` and `/g` symbolise a new Regular Expression. The `^` symbolises the start of the word. The `logo-` symbolises that the start of the word contains the string `logo-`. The `[^ ]` symbolises that it will have a character that isn't a space after it and the `*` symbolises that there will be one or more characters that isn't a space.

Comment: Regular expressions work on strings. How would you apply that to selecting DOM elements as in the question?

Comment: @nnnnnn `document.getElementByClassName()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Do a `document.querySelectorAll('[class*="logo-"]');`.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin - Sure, but that's not using regular expressions. This answer says it can be done with regular expressions.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah. Google brought me to this question because I was trying to select parts of a string. (Specifically, I was trying to grab all classes on an element that began with `type-` ). Ironically, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the search class is inside classes list. One way is to read all classes and than extract the required type of classes.
Here is the sample working code. I have not added code to check for uniqueness in search results for class list.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var allLogoClasses = [];
    // add classes to tab items
    var listItems = $(".vc_tta-tab a");
    // loop through all tab items
    listItems.each(function(idx, item) {
    var listItem = $(item);
    var tabID = listItem.attr("href");
 var classes = $(tabID).attr('class');
 if(classes) {
  classes = classes.split(" ");
  for(var index = 0; index < classes.length; index++) {
   if(classes[index].startsWith("logo-")) {
    allLogoClasses.push(classes[index]);
   }
  }
 }
 });
 console.log(allLogoClasses);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_general vc_tta vc_tta-tabs vc_tta-color-grey vc_tta-style-classic vc_tta-shape-rounded vc_tta-spacing-1 vc_tta-tabs-position-top vc_tta-controls-align-left">
   <div class="vc_tta-tabs-container">
      <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
         <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-symantec" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Symantec SSL/TLS Certificates</span></a></li>
         <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-geotrust" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">GeoTrust SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
         <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-rapidssl" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">RapidSSL Certificates</span></a></li>
         <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-thawte" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Thawte SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
         <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-certum" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Certum SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
         <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#ssl-brand-comodo" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Comodo SSL Certificates</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="vc_tta-panels-container">
      <div class="vc_tta-panels">
         <div class="vc_tta-panel vc_active logo-ssl-symantec" id="ssl-brand-symantec" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
               <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-symantec" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Symantec SSL/TLS Certificates</span></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-geotrust" id="ssl-brand-geotrust" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
               <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-geotrust" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">GeoTrust SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-rapidssl" id="ssl-brand-rapidssl" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
               <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-rapidssl" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">RapidSSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-thawte" id="ssl-brand-thawte" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
               <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-thawte" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Thawte SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-certum" id="ssl-brand-certum" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
               <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-certum" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Certum SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_tta-panel logo-ssl-comodo" id="ssl-brand-comodo" data-vc-content=".vc_tta-panel-body">
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-heading">
               <h4 class="vc_tta-panel-title"><a href="#ssl-brand-comodo" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Comodo SSL Certificates</span></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="vc_tta-panel-body"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The other way is to grab the required class using regular expression from the class list string.

I hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the current item class using the jQuery **is** method as follows:

`if($(item).is('[class^="logo-"]'))`

Find a simple working example in here: https://codepen.io/jpgcode/pen/GEdQRp